# C - Output value not calculating correctly

Tags: c, output

I'm just started to learn how to code and decided to try to create a program that would calculate the amount of calories a person burns based on certain values that are asked of them. However, whenever I run it instead of getting the calculated value based on their values I keep getting the value 2686708. I just can't seem to make it work no matter what.

```
//included libraries
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>

//constants
#define WALKING_CAL 5
#define EXERCISING_CAL 10
#define EATING_CAL 40
#define DRINKING_CAL 20
#define CALORIES_PER_POUND 3500*/

//main function
int main() {

int current_weight, goal_weight;
int walking, exercise, drinking, eating;
int total_walking, total_exercising, total_eating, total_drinking;
int calories_burned, calories_gained;

printf("What is your current weight?\n");
scanf("%d", &current_weight);

printf("\nWhat is your goal weight?\n");
scanf("%d", &goal_weight);

total_walking = WALKING_CAL * walking;
total_exercising = EXERCISING_CAL * exercise;
total_eating = EATING_CAL * eating;
total_drinking = DRINKING_CAL * drinking;
calories_burned = (total_walking + total_exercising)- (total_eating + total_drinking);


if (goal_weight > current_weight){
    printf("\nHow many minutes do you walk per day?\n");
    scanf("%d", &walking);

    printf("\nHow many minutes do you exercise per day?\n");
    scanf("%d", &exercise);

    printf("\nHow many minutes do you drink per day?\n");
    scanf("%d", &drinking);

    printf("\nHow many minutes do you eat per day?\n");
    scanf("%d", &eating);


    printf("You gain %d calories per day.", &calories_burned);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line `#define CALORIES_PER_POUND 3500*/` shouldn't have the close comment symbol on it.

Comment: Moreover you printf an integer and you pass a pointer to it: per     day.", calories_burned);

Comment: Also you need to input your variables *before* doing calculations with them !

Comment: I'd recommend you to start learning in C++, not C, there is less pitfall when using C++'s possibilities.

Comment: I had commented off the #define section before posting this since I was testing something and I missed taking out the close comment symbol. Thanks for all the help guys. I finally got it to work like I wanted to.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
printf("You gain %d calories per day.", &calories_burned);
```

prints *the address* of the variable, not the variable's value (as an `int`, which in turn is undefined behavior but seems to not blow up for you at least).

It should be:

```
printf("You gain %d calories per day.", calories_burned);
```

Drop the `&`.

Comment: This is a common new-to-C programmer error because you need `&int_variable` for `scanf()`, but just `int_variable` for `printf()` -- this is because scanf needs to change the value of `int_variable` while printf just needs to look at it.